# Python 3 single object from multiple instances

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I am trying to track droplets of a video. From every frame, I end up with multiple droplets and noise detected (using findcontours).

From frame A, I generate X objects defined by:

```
class Object:
    'Creates new object containing the location and its respective pixel frame.' 
    objectCount=0
    def __init__(self,position,frame):
        self.position=position
        self.pixelframe=frame[position-10:position+10,position-10:position+10]
        Object.objectCount+=1
```

Now, what I then do is compare that pixelframe centered with the centroid (position) of the object of frame A with frame B. I use the structural similarity index (SSIM) to give me a value of the similarity between two frame. If the match is perfect (or nearly), the object hasn't moved and is considered as a background one (unimportant). However, if it has moved (bad match), I need to find it in frame B. In order to do that, I compare the pixel frame of the object in frame A with one in frame B until I find a good match. Once I have a good match, I'd like to associate these two object as a single one (Droplet).

As example to illustrate my problem let's say I have 10 objects from frame A: obj11, obj12, ..., obj110
After testing, only obj1 has moved (bad match for the same location).
frame B has 12 objects: obj21,obj22,...,obj212
After verification, obj11 and obj21 have a very good match and can be associated together as being a Droplet.

What I had in mind was to create a Droplet class that would inherit the attributes of obj11 and obj21.

```
class Droplet:
    def __init__(self,objectA,objectB):
        self.data=[objectA,objectB]
    def add(self,objectC):
        self.data.append(objectC)
```

Am I doing it correctly? Would there be a better way instead of creating two classes?

Comment: Is there a reason why you need a special class and can't just use e.g. a list nested in a dictionary?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams, how would you do such list nested in a dic? I am a big noob.